# inner joining on a update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check if the user owns a course, I am trying to do this by getting the transaction_id (someone who's applied to a course) and then left join the courses and check the course_user against a session where the transaction_course is equal to course id

**My SQL**

```
UPDATE training_transactions 
       LEFT JOIN training 
              ON training_transactions.training_transaction_id = 
                 training.course_id 
SET    training_transactions.training_transaction_status = 'declined' 
WHERE  training_transactions.training_transaction_id = ? 
       AND training.course_user = ?
```

**training_transaction:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_transactions` (
  `training_transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_course` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_enabled` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `training_transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**training**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_fitness_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_instructor_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_price` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `course_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `course_max_attendees` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `course_enabled` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So my question, how can I update if the transaction id matches the course_id and the user's session (below) matches the course_user?

```
Session::get('id') // user id
```

Comment: Why are you using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: You don't need `training_transacdtion_id` in the `WHERE` clause. You already matched that in the `ON` clause, that's all that's needed.

Comment: Because I need to select that row with an id, I matched it in the on, so the inner join knows which row in courses to select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be testing `training_transaction_course` in the `WHEN` clause, not `training_transaction_id`. And you should use `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`; you only need `LEFT JOIN` if you need to get rows in the first table that have no matches in the second table.

```
UPDATE training_transactions AS tt
INNER JOIN training AS t ON tt.training_transaction_id = t.course_id 
SET tt.training_transaction_status = 'declined' 
WHERE tt.training_transaction_course = ? 
   AND t.course_user = ?
```